# JavaScript Printing Twice

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
function Person() {
  throw new Error("The person is abstract  constructor function");
}

Person.prototype.personName = "John";
Person.prototype.age = 21;
Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person name ${this.personName} and age is ${this.age}.`;
};

function Teacher() {}

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Teacher.prototype.mainSubject = "Physics";
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `${this.__proto__.getDetails()} main subject is ${this.mainSubject} `;
};

var teacher1 = new Teacher();
console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

Its printing ''Person name John and age is 21. main subject is Physics  main subject is Physics''. This line main subject is Physics should not come twice.

Person name John and age is 21. main subject is Physics .

Comment: try with debugger to check is getting called twice your `Teacher.prototype.getDetails` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding getDetails of Person with Teacher

```js
function Person() {
  throw new Error("The person is abstract  constructor function");
}

Person.prototype.personName = "John";
Person.prototype.age = 21;
Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person name ${this.personName} and age is ${this.age}.`;
};

function Teacher() {}

Teacher.prototype.person = Object.create(Person.prototype); // Here changed
Teacher.prototype.mainSubject = "Physics";
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `${this.person.getDetails()} main subject is ${this.mainSubject} `; // Here changed
};

var teacher1 = new Teacher();
console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

Comment: @Cerbrus we can not create instance Person like `new Person()`.